Difficulty understanding this covid formula
I am having difficulty understanding this formula over here on "Provincial Covid-19 Stringency Index (SI)" described in this link https://www.bankofcanada.ca/2021/02/staff-analytical-note-2021-1/. I was hoping someone could help me walk through the formula to confirm if my understanding is on the right track.
I tried my best to understand how the SI is calculated for each province. According to the link, for a given province, each sub-index $I_j$ is:
$$ I_j = 100 \cdot \frac{v_j - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_j} $$
Where:

$I_j$ is the sub-index score for policy indicator $j$

$v_j$ is the ordinal value for the most restrictive measures in place within the province for policy $j$

$F$ is the number of targeting dimensions for policy $j$

$f_i$ is the flag for targeting dimension $i$, which equals 1 if the policy is general or 0 if targeted

$N_j$ is the maximum possible value for policy indicator $j$


Then, the overall stringency index is then calculated as the simple average of all sub-indexes:
$$ \text{Stringency Index} = \frac{1}{12} \sum_{j=1}^{12} I_j $$

The terminology is a bit confusing for me, but it seems that a "dimension" refers to a way in which a policy can be targeted or general.
Based on the link, Dimensions are specific aspects of a policy that can be either targeted (applying to specific groups or areas) or general (applying to everyone). For each policy indicator, there can be multiple dimensions. For example, the school closure policy (C1) has three dimensions:

Geography (targeted to specific regions or entire province)
Demographic (targeted to specific grades or all grades)
Class type (online classes replacing in-person, or all classes cancelled)

Thus, in the formula:
$$ I_j = 100 \cdot \frac{v_j - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_j} $$
$F$ represents the total number of dimensions for policy $j$
$f_i$ is the flag for dimension $i$, where:
$$ f_i = \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if the policy is general in this dimension} \\
      0 & \text{if the policy is targeted in this dimension}
   \end{cases} $$
The term $0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)$ in the formula adjusts the policy's ordinal value based on how targeted it is:

If all dimensions are general ($\sum_i f_i = F$), this term becomes zero
For each targeted dimension, this term increases, reducing the overall score


On the other hand, the concept of "max value" was also confusing to me since I thought that for a given policy, the sum of the flags (if all flags were 1) must equal to the max value. However, I don't think is true. .
For example:

If a province requires closing for some sectors (ordinal value 2),
applies it to the entire province (Geography = 1),
but allows partial opening (Opening = 0),

The calculation would be:
$$ I_2 = 100 \cdot \frac{v_2 - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_2} = 100 \cdot \frac{2 - 0.5(2 - 1)}{4} = 37.5 $$
The targeting dimensions don't determine the maximum value. Instead, they adjust the score downward if the policy is more targeted, within the range set by the ordinal value scale (0-4). Intuitively, this approach allows the index to capture both the overall strictness of the policy and how broadly it's applied, providing a more nuanced measure of stringency.

Finally, to confirm my understanding, I tried to create a detailed example with multiple policies and dimensions. For example, on some given day, consider the provincial stringency index using three policy indicators: school closures ($C_1$), workplace closures ($C_2$), and public event cancellations ($C_3$).
Policy 1: School closures ($C_1$)

Ordinal value: Require closing all school types ($v₁$ = 3)
Dimensions:

Geography: Entire province ($f₁$ = 1)
Demographic: All grades ($f₂$ = 1)
Class: Online classes replace in-person ($f₃$ = 0)


Maximum value: $N₁$ = 3

$$ I_1 = 100 \cdot \frac{v_1 - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_1} = 100 \cdot \frac{3 - 0.5(3 - 2)}{3} = 100 \cdot \frac{2.5}{3} = 83.33 $$
Policy 2: Workplace closures ($C_2$)

Ordinal value: Require closing for all but a broad set of essential workplaces ($v₂$ = 3)
Dimensions:

Geography: Entire province ($f₁$ = 1)
Opening: Partial opening allowed ($f₂$ = 0)


Maximum value: $N₂$ = 4

$$ I_2 = 100 \cdot \frac{v_2 - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_2} = 100 \cdot \frac{3 - 0.5(2 - 1)}{4} = 100 \cdot \frac{2.5}{4} = 62.5 $$
Policy 3: Public event cancellations ($C_3$)

Ordinal value: Cancel events with more than 50 attendees ($v₃$ = 3)
Dimensions:

Geography: Targeted region ($f₁$ = 0)
Event: Some events exempt ($f₂$ = 0)
Outdoor/Indoor: Different restrictions ($f₃$ = 0)


Maximum value: $N₃$ = 4

$$ I_3 = 100 \cdot \frac{v_3 - 0.5(F - \sum_i f_i)}{N_3} = 100 \cdot \frac{3 - 0.5(3 - 0)}{4} = 100 \cdot \frac{1.5}{4} = 37.5 $$
Thus, the provincial stringency index based on these three policies:
$$ \text{Provincial Stringency Index} = \frac{1}{3} (I_1 + I_2 + I_3) $$
$$ \text{Provincial Stringency Index} = \frac{1}{3} (83.33 + 62.5 + 37.5) = 61.11 $$
In a full calculation (i.e. all 12 policy indicators), we would repeat this process for all 12 policy indicators. The final formula would be:
$$ \text{Provincial Stringency Index} = \frac{1}{12} \sum_{j=1}^{12} I_j $$

Is my understanding of this somewhat correct?

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be a mathematics question.
